# HTML5 audio element plays twice and how to auto play on smartphone

Tags: html, audio, joomla, autoplay

I have a problem with the `audio` element.

I mean that if I put this eleent on a page, the audio starts **twice** (with a little delay).

The code is the following:

```
<audio src="images/audio/basemusicale.mp3" autoplay="autoplay"
  controls="controls" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

I use the latest Joomla version (3.4.4).

And how can I automatically play it on a smartphone too?

I have seen that in a smartphone it doesn't autoplay (like, on a Nexus 4).

Thank you in advance at all.

I attend your answers. Thanks

Comment: sorry, this is the tag (it was delated on a question):
<audio src="images/audio/basemusicale.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

Comment: The code above is correct and shouldn't start twice. If it does, it could be because it is triggered twice in your code, or maybe you have duplicated the audio on the page. As for the automatically play on mobile devices, you can check [numerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499341) [on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075520) [about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827397) [that topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107878): autoplay is disabled in mobile devices to avoid unsolicited use of bandwidth