# YT autoplay on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube-api

So I am working on making a website for myself and it contains a looping youtube video in the background. But when I try to load the page on a mobile device the youtube video just keeps buffering and ends up telling me to restart. 
I know that autoplay isnt supposed to work on mobile devices, but the video clearly tries to start.

Is there a way to fix this?

The page is AMolle.com if you have the time to check it out=)

Comment: You could create an array *(hold the video id's `v=xxxxx`)*, use the youtube players event listener to wait for the first video to end so it will play the next one and loop through the videos that way?

Comment: @NewToJS What I was trying to ask for was a way to auto-start the video, because I have looping covered

Comment: Then use `playVideo();` .....

Comment: Problem is, it does not work on mobile devices

Comment: Ah I see. I read part of the question wrong. My apologies *just woke up*

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if there is a legal way on how to make auto play videos possible on the mobile device. The reason for the `autoplay`, `playVideo()` and `loadVideoById()` to do not work on mobile device is to prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at the user’s expense and embedded media cannot be played automatically.

The other people use the [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview) as an alternative for the IOS device to make the autoplay work. Check these threads for more information.

- [no autoplay in iframe HTML5 player on mobile (Android Chrome and Firefox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959454/no-autoplay-in-iframe-html5-player-on-mobile-android-chrome-and-firefox)
- [how to get embedded youtube video to autostart on iphone](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28364423/how-to-get-embedded-youtube-video-to-autostart-on-iphone.html)
- [Youtube autoplay not working on mobile devices with embedded HTML5 player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090782/youtube-autoplay-not-working-on-mobile-devices-with-embedded-html5-player)