# Iframe responsive autoplay video not working

Tags: html, jquery, css, iframe

**Im simply using iframe with video embed link, its working on desktop but not working in mobile devices.**

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/7Exa5g_I7ec?feature=oembed&enablejsapi=1&origin=https://www2.gemseducation.com&rel=0&autoplay=1&mute=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&playlist=7Exa5g_I7ec&background=1&mute=1&loop=1
```

is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Youtube embed autoplay on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399390/youtube-embed-autoplay-on-mobile)

Comment: that is the iframe code which im using but its only working on desktop not mobile

Answer (score 0):

This is likely intentional behaviour to prevent mobile data from being used without knowledge.

You can see more details here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations

It has also been discussed on Stack Overflow before here:
[Youtube embed autoplay on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399390/youtube-embed-autoplay-on-mobile)